# Android:How to programmatically set an Activity's theme to Theme.Dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes

So I have an `Activity` (say `TestActivity`) which needs to act as a normal unthemed `Activity` as well as a `Theme.Dialog` at other place. I am trying to reuse same `TestActivity` for both the tasks.

All I am looking for setting the theme dynamically.
The code is simple:
Here is my activity's `onCreate` that works with a black background

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    if (Utility.isDialog == true)
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
.....
```

and here is the Manifest Entry

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"/>
```

And in the meantime I found a post that says it can't be done here is the post http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394 .But there is a strong feeling that it can be done.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Should I accept that there is **no solution** to this question as this [post](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394) says?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Would like to give a work around for this problem.

Problem : How to use the same activity as both dialog and full screen based.

Solution :

1. Define your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml with the theme `@android:style/Theme.Dialog`
2. In your respective `.Java` file, check for an `intent` extra that defines `dialog` mode.
3. If it does not exist, set the `Theme` to `android.R.style.Theme`. This is the default `theme` which is applied if you do not define any theme.

Code :

```
boolean fDialogMode = getIntent().hasExtra("dialog_mode");

if( ! fDialogMode ) {
    super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
}
```

Alternate Solution:

A more complex solution is to use `AlertDialog` as below:

1. Define a `ListAdapter` class extended from `ArrayAdapter`.
2. return `1` in `getCount` function

   ```
   @Override
   public int getCount() { return 1; }
   ```
3. In the `getView` function, `inflate` the `layout` of the `activity` you need and do any customization before returning the `view`.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView( int position, View view, ViewGroup group ) {
       View v = view;
       if( v == null ) {
           v = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate( <layout res id>, null );
       }

   ... Do any customization here    ....

         return v;
   }
   ```

This is definitely a second choice option by if you are not doing too much processing in the `activity` `class` this could be an option.

Only reason to consider this solution could be that the logic to show it in a `dialog` is isolated to the places where it is used as a dialog.

Both the options worked for me but for obvious reasons I am taking the first option. :-)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! If someone don't get it at the first time (like me :D) - read @mozarty solution first to understand where exactly you should put this code.

Answer (score 45):

you can use `setTheme(..)` before calling `setContentView(...)`and `super.oncreate()`  and it should work fine

Comment: you are not calling setContentView , and i know that it can be done because i did it in my activity

Comment: Moving the call to setTheme before the super.onCreate made it work for me, thank you!

Comment: Just a FYI: This does work, but it creates an enormous lag in creating a new activity for some reason (on Kindle Fire) and it makes my app crash unexpectedly on the Nook Color.

Comment: i never tried it on Kindle before , thx for the info , will have to test it when i get one

Comment: This solution doesn't work for all devices. Consider the Motorola Xoom, the result is a dialog on top of a black background rather than a transparent one.

Comment: @user933237 that is interesting , i also found out that what you described happens on ACER iconia tablet

Answer (score 11):

Like several others, calls to setTheme in onCreate (before or after my call to super.onCreate) did not work. However, by overriding setTheme, I was able to specify a theme other than that stated in Manifest.xml. Specifically, the following worked without issue:

```
@Override
public void setTheme(int resid) {
    boolean changeTheme = true;
    super.setTheme(changeTheme ? android.R.style.Theme_Dialog : resid);
}
```

I found the above in the discussion at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394

Comment: However, with Android invoking setTheme() before the onCreate() call, one can't use the data normally sent to an activity to decide whether to change the theme. Some additional hack is needed to make that decision.

Answer (score 10):

Call [`Activity.setTheme()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)) in `onCreate()` before you call `setContentView()`.

Comment: Reuben though it works (& I have tried that earlier too)but I see Black Background instead of the calling Activity

Comment: Then your theme properties are incorrect. What is your android:windowBackground set to?

Comment: Reuben I have not defined a custom style.But I will now implement a custom style with windowBackground to color/transparent

Comment: Reuben even the custom style didn't worked.For your answer to windowBackgound see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/2700683#2700683

Comment: see the updated post with the code.Do let me know for more details.

Comment: is it possible to call the setTheme after setContentView, if i call setContentView again (this time after setTheme) ? example of a scenario: user sees the activity, press a button, and it changes the theme by calling setTheme and then setContentView.

Answer (score 3):

use `setTheme` before calling `super.onCreate(savedInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be applicable in your situation, but you can use the theme:

```
Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge
```

and it will display your activity as a dialog when the screen is large, and as a regular activity when the screen is small.
This is covered in the Android documentation on [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog) and also contains information on programming a Dialog which can also sun as a full screen fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Default theme library call:

```
super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
```

In my case I was using AppCompat Theme, so make sure that on your id you refer the proper library (i.e.):

```
super.setTheme(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

Comment: please take some time to explain how this solves the problem so that other with similar problem can know the issue clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I know that I am late but I would like to post a solution here:

Check the full source code [here](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/10/implementing-users-choice-themeapply.html). This is the code I used when changing theme...

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
       .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String themeName = pref.getString("prefSyncFrequency3", "Theme1");
if (themeName.equals("Africa")) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
} else if (themeName.equals("Colorful Beach")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setTheme(R.style.beach);
} else if (themeName.equals("Abstract")) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "set theme", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setTheme(R.style.abstract2);
} else if (themeName.equals("Default")) {
    setTheme(R.style.defaulttheme);
}
```