# Hide the status bar,but my view does not go to the top

Tags: android, hide, statusbar

I use

```
mContext.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
mContext.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
mContext.getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();
```

to hide the status bar after setContentView.
The status bar is hided,but my view does not go to the top.There is a black rectangle
instead of the status bar.

Comment: What is your test device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the Manifest file of that particular activity. remove above code from java file and put below code in Manifest in the activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Somewhere I need hide the status bar,but others do not.The code hide everywhere

Comment: so you can add in those activities where you want to hide and other activities leave as it is.

Comment: There is just one activity!

Comment: Then you have to do it by code. please refere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967904/androidhow-to-programmatically-set-an-activitys-theme-to-theme-dialog

Comment: I have solve it.I use a surfaceview and change its size.Then the view go to the top!!!

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution : just check it out

```
// hide titlebar of application
    // must be before setting the layout
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // hide statusbar of Android
    // could also be done later
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Somewhere I need hide the status bar,but others do not.The code hide everywhere

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the status bar please add request feture with `no title` and flag as `full screen` then 
add the content view.

Code is

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
```

And for only the notification bar

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```